# PHP Parse error but it's everything okay, whta'ts wrong

Tags: php, syntax

I'm beginner in PHP and I want put a condition on my code but when I tried the PHP have an error on my index. 
**Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' in C:\xampp\htdocs\customers\index.php on line 150**

This is the lines:

```
<td class="actions text-right">
              <a href="view.php?id=<?php echo $customer['id']; ?>" class="btn btn-sm btn-success"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i> Visualizar</a>
              <?php if ($_SESSION['UsuarioNivel'] > 2) {
                  <a href="edit.php?id=<?php echo $customer['id']; ?>" class="btn btn-sm btn-warning"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> Editar
                  </a>
              } if ($_SESSION['UsuarioNivel'] = 3){
                  <a href="#" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#delete-modal" data-customer="<?php echo $customer['id']; ?>">
            <i class="fa fa-trash"></i> Excluir </a>
              } ?>
              </td>
```

The IF statement is wrong? How do I can do this?

Comment: I don't see nothing duplicate. I just see my problem.

Comment: You aren't closing the PHP context (ie, `?>`) after you `if` statements. You need to do that before you drop back into normal HTML

Comment: I solved my problem, thanks.